# how to set first row of listview as invisible?

Tags: android

How to set first row of `listview` as `invisible`?

Adapter's `getView`

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(position == 0)
            convertView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        else
            convertView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         return convertView;
    }
```

Hides all the contents of first row but leaves the blank space.
any suggestions?

Comment: this should be done in Adapter, not in ListView. Change Adapter to omit data for that row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making it `invisible` or `gone` you filter the items and display it in listview.

Implement a custom filter.

Edit:

Use the code in the link below. It works

http://www.sherif.mobi/2012/01/listview-with-ability-to-hide-rows.html

Example: To hide row 3

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView lv;
    String items[]={"A","B","C","D","E"};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        CustomAdapter cus = new CustomAdapter(this,items);
        cus.hide(2);// hide letter c
        lv.setAdapter(cus);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

CustomAdapter.java

```
class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    String items[];
    boolean[] hidden = null;
    public CustomAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, String[] items) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mainActivity);
        this.items=items;
        hidden = new boolean[items.length]; 
        for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
               hidden[i] = false;
    }
    private int getRealPosition(int position) {
         int hElements = getHiddenCountUpTo(position);
         int diff = 0;
         for(int i=0;i<hElements;i++) {
          diff++;
          if(hidden[position+diff])
           i--;
         }
         return (position + diff);
        }
        private int getHiddenCountUpTo(int location) {
         int count = 0;
         for(int i=0;i<=location;i++) {
          if(hidden[i])
           count++;
         }
         return count;
        }

    public void hide(int position) {
         hidden[getRealPosition(position)] = true;
         notifyDataSetChanged();
         notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        }
        public void unHide(int position) {
         hidden[getRealPosition(position)] = false;
         notifyDataSetChanged();
         notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
     return (items.length - getHiddenCount());
    }

    private int getHiddenCount() {
     int count = 0;
     for(int i=0;i<items.length;i++)
      if(hidden[i])
       count++;
     return count;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewHolder holder; 

        int pos = getRealPosition(position);
        if (convertView == null) { 
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder(); 
            holder.tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
            holder.tv2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2); 
           convertView.setTag(holder); 
       } else { 
           holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(); 
       } 
        holder.tv.setText("Postion at"+pos); 
        holder.tv2.setText("Item is "+items[pos]);
        return convertView;
    }
static class ViewHolder
{
    TextView tv,tv2;
}
}
```

row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Snap shot

[image]

Comment: @user2978175 doesn't work. what do you mean by that? what you shown you have not even inflated the layout

Comment: @user2978175 You need to set height of that view with 1 or 2 dip. I don't think you can set GONE with List row...

Comment: @PankajKumar oh yes. its not for the view its for the row

Comment: i have inflated the layout. just posted the code that i have used for hiding the first row. it only hides the first wor content but the empty space is still there.

Comment: @user2978175 why make the row invisible?

Comment: first row contains the  data that shouldnot be visible to user. i cannot modify the list of data that has to be assigned with the listview.

Comment: @user2978175 you can implement a custom filter and display only those items that you require for example a search on listview will filter items related to search criteria

Comment: @user2978175 i found a link which i guess suits you. check the edit now

Comment: @user2978175 check the edit now posted a example that hides row 3. you can use the same to hide row 0 solution found at the link posted. check the snap shot

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(position == 0)
        convertView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    else
        convertView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     return convertView;
}
```